# Fatal error: Call to undefined method ConnectDatabase::query()

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i have created an OOP-PHP Script and i get follow Message and i don't understand why???

Fatal error: Call to undefined method ConnectDatabase::query() in .... on line 73

My PHP Code

```
<?php

class ConnectDatabase {

private $host = 'localhost';
private $username = 'root';
private $password = '';
private $database = 'database';
private $db_connection;
private $db_query;

//Connect Database.
  function __construct() {
  $this->open_db();
}

public function query($sql) {
 $this->db_query = query($sql, $this->db_connection);
}

public function open_db() {

$this->db_connection = new mysqli($this->host, $this->username, $this->password);

if (is_resource($this->db_connection)) {
  die("Error!");
 } else {
  $this->db_connection->select_db($this->database) or die('Error');
  }
 }
}

$dbConnection = new ConnectDatabase();

class GetContent {

 public function newContent() {
 global $dbConnection;
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable";
 // ----- This Line make an Error ------
 $query = $dbConnection->query($sql);
 $found = $dbConnection->fetch_array($query);
 return $found;
 }
}
```

If you have any Idea please help.

Comment: Shouldn't that be mysqli_query, not just query() in the query-function?

Comment: "global" fleeee

Comment: I want to use actual mysqli. What happen with global?

Comment: You shouldn't be using globals in class-functions.

Comment: `OOP` doesn't mean "we used the `class` keyword, so we have done it". If you want use `globals`, then your classes are more an impediment than helpful.

Comment: (1) `query()` in  `query($sql, $this->db_connection);` should be `mysqli_query()`. (2) your parameters in `query($sql, $this->db_connection);` need the order switched. So it should be `mysqli_query($this->db_connection, $sql);`